# Computation inside select statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, select

I have a stored procedure where i am selcting 10 cols based on a condition. Nothing fancy just `SELECT col 1 - 10 WHERE date is between x and y`. One of the selected columns contains a bit switch. I want to be able to check that bit switch and if its 1 assign a value based on some math to a column else assign based on some alternate math.

```
SELECT col1...col10 
FROM table a
WHERE getDate is BETWEEN x AND y

IF col5 = 1 THEN
   col10 = quantity - quantitysold
ELSE
   col10 = quantity - SUM(quantitysold, yearlyonhand)
```

is the basic idea. Is what I am attempting to so way off the mark? it seems like a simple enough concept, I am just not sure how to make it work.

My other thought was to perhaps create a udf that handled the computation and call that function from inside the sproc if the bit switch was 1 and an alternate function if not. This seems like an abnormal amount of work for a relatively simple concept though.

Comment: Accept answer on previous question you have asked!

Comment: my apologies i thought i had done so. I have gone back and done this where applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `case` statement:

```
select col1, .... , 
      case col5 when 0 then ... 
                when 1 then ... , 
       col6, .... 
Where
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the quantity, quantitysold etc are columns from the table or do the join if needed...

```
SELECT
    col1...,
    CASE
        WHEN col5 = 1 THEN quantity - TotalSoldToday
        ELSE quantity - (TotalSoldToday + yearlyonhand) 
    END AS col10 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Sum(Quantity) as TotalSoldToday
    FROM
        table a
    WHERE
        Convert(Date, DateColumn) = Convert(Date, GETDATE())
) T on 1 = 1
FROM
    table a
WHERE
    DateColumn is BETWEEN x AND y
```

Comment: They are a part of the selected list, no join necessary. I will attempt this solution, and see if it works. It looks like what was off, was my syntax in my case statement.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention the quantity formula being used needs to utilize built in functions. basically if the switch = 1 quantity = dailylimit - how many sold today. so something like:

quantity = col5 - count(totalsold) today

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
update table
set col10 = (case when col5 = 1 then quantity - quantitysold else quantity - quantitysold + yearlyonhand end)
where getDate between x and y
```

Comment: I am not looking to update the table. basically return information. The only side note is one of the columns i am returning needs to be computed. The computation is dependent on the value of a bit switch from the table. If the switch is true the total to return would be quantity - quantitysold(today) else the total to return would be quantity - quantitysold(forever). Does that make more sense?